# How do I structure my code for server side rendering in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, facebook, meteor, seo, server-side-rendering

So I currently have a Meteor site where I would like to use server side rendering for Facebook open graph meta tags and SEO purposes (I know Google now can spider client side rendered pages but other search engines can't).

So I'm following this guide (https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-server-sider-rendering-for-seo-purpose/) and it seems like I'm basically just duplicating every view I want SEO-ed into the private folder.

That sounds like an awful lot of duplication. What would be a good pattern or structure I can lay out my code so that I share as much of the client views and server views as possible?